# Does your name belong to you?

Tags: british-english, possessives

I'm having trouble deciding whether the word 'name' can be used possessively.  Currently I'm thinking it's correct to say:

> **Patients' names** have been altered to provide anonymity

However it just doesn't look right to me.  Is the above correct for a group of patients or would any of the following be better:

> - **Patients names** have been altered to provide anonymity
> - **Patient names** have been altered to provide anonymity

Comment: Think of it less as possessive and more as [genitive](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/genitive?q=genitive).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Patients' names have been altered to provide anonymity

This is correct.

> Patients names have been altered to provide anonymity

This is not.

> Patient names have been altered to provide anonymity

I believe most AE speakers would find this acceptable.

Comment: the 3rd suggests as if a patient has multiple names, right?

Comment: @camelbrush, not really.  Although it doesn't exclude that.

Comment: ... however impatient names have been left unchanged to shame them in public....

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course your name belongs to you. That fact notwithstanding, only two of your sentences are correct:

> Patients' names have been altered to provide anonymity.

and

> Patient names have been altered to provide anonymity.

There are other ways of saying the same thing, e.g.:

> The names of the patients have been altered to protect their privacy.

I see sentences like these on occasion in the biomed articles I edit every day.